# Is there any existing obfuscation scheme that makes cipher text indistinguishable from plain text?

Tags: encryption

Suppose a totalitarian government (in the name of anti-terrorism / protection of intellectual property):

1. has outlawed encryption itself - encryption is only approved for cases where the state has reviewed the design and made sure it can decrypt/inspect the message, and made any unapproved encryption a criminal offense
2. has total control over anything in and out of the network at ISP-level, as well as anything that passes through web services

How could two citizens Alice and Bob, using approved (and monitored) instant messaging service to set up a secure line of communication, conceal the fact that the communication is encrypted, i.e. to make it indistinguishable from unencrypted data, or at least, make it computationally- or financially-infeasible to distinguish it from plain text?

For example, no one would assume the following message to be encrypted:

- > Across the Great Wall, we can reach every corner in the world.

But it would be assumed that the following is:

- > WZ2A805Wq3rzpiuzE+ZCulgDrn76pVRW5PVUJ4DDadFQD4P9PsTeegbo5CAkqI4yZrO//p
  >   sYT+ZQkqZ6IrSGng==
- > 599D80F34E56AB7AF3A62BB313E642BA
  >   5803AE7EFAA55456E4F5542780C369D1
  >   500F83FD3EC4DE7A06E8E42024A88E32
  >   66B3BFFE9B184FE65092A67A22B4869E

For the purpose of this question, we assume the following technical details:

1. the IM service is text-only, binary data is not allowed (in an IM setting, sending primarily small binary fragments back and forth would probably raise suspicion anyway)
2. communication between Alice and the IM service, Bob and the IM service, are both end-to-end encrypted. A government agent Eve has a copy of the decryption key the IM service used
3. proof that the message is encrypted is not required. I.e. Eve does not need to know the plain text or the algorithm used to produce the cipher text. She only needs to tell, with a reasonably-low false-positive rate, if a message is the result of an encryption
4. the endpoint is secure, no backdoor or malware on the computer/router, etc.

I'd like to know if there are any reliable research on this, is it feasible or not, and if feasible, any existing protocol or algorithm developed for this?

<sub>Eve, in case you are watching, I'm asking this for academic purposes only.</sub>

Comment: There was a question about mapping the ciphertext to words, that I've failed to find it now. A good way, actually, is stenography combined with encryption.

Comment: And for Eve, we don't care about your prohibition. Secrecy is a part of the our life.

Comment: This is called steganography. Bunch of info online. Common technique is to use certain bits in an image or audio stream.

Comment: If you're confined to text, there are a bunch of old classical techniques (e.g. every Nth word with the real message, or the third word after a misspelling) that might be adapted (although it might be difficult to automate them - it might be difficult to have a computer generate a convincing outer text, and using (say) a text passage from a book might be dangerous if someone finds the original text...

Comment: @poncho I don't know for certain, but I'd imagine that every-nth-word would be susceptible to ML-backed natural language processing? Because the construct would be far from meaningful in any way (unless we spend considerably more time for each message, and have to be done manually). It's still much better than base64 encoding though.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "adapted", rather than "adopted".  You'd have to replace techniques that are hard for programs (such as finding a plausible way to insert a specific word) with ones which are easier (for example, finding a plausible text with the 7th letter as a vowel)

Comment: Steganography of some kind is probably the only viable approach, but (as I understand things), they necessarily have a very low "bit-rate" (of the secret message).A sudden increase in the volume of messages between Alice and Bob would probably be the biggest signal that steganography was being used, so you'd either need an already verbose channel, or should plan on ramping up the volume gradually over time (during which _no_ steganography should be used).

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned, what you're asking for is a form of *steganography*,which may or may not use encrypted content.

The classic approach derives from talking around the subject (Crimes and Spies) as in:

"*The Apple crates are Golden Delicious. There are 15 crates.*"

A more technical approach I've seen is  [Spam Mimmic](http://spammimic.com/index.cgi)

Spam Mimmic encode:  **Bob, meet me at the secret lair at 1900.**

Spam Mimmic decode:

> Dear Friend , We know you are interested in receiving  red-hot news !
>   This is a one time mailing there is  no need to request removal if you
>   won't want any more  . This mail is being sent in compliance with
>   Senate  bill 1626 ; Title 1 , Section 307 ! THIS IS NOT MULTI-LEVEL 
>   MARKETING ! Why work for somebody else when you can  become rich
>   inside 31 DAYS ! Have you ever noticed  the baby boomers are more
>   demanding than their parents  plus how many people you know are on the
>   Internet !  Well, now is your chance to capitalize on this . WE  will
>   help YOU use credit cards on your website plus  increase customer
>   response by 120% ! You can begin  at absolutely no cost to you ! But
>   don't believe us  . Mr Anderson who resides in Montana tried us and
>   says  "My only problem now is where to park all my cars"  ! We are
>   licensed to operate in all states . For the  sake of your family order
>   now ! Sign up a friend and  you'll get a discount of 10% . Thanks .
>   Dear Internet  user , This letter was specially selected to be sent 
>   to you ! If you are not interested in our publications  and wish to be
>   removed from our lists, simply do NOT  respond and ignore this mail .
>   This mail is being sent  in compliance with Senate bill 1620 ; Title 9
>   , Section  303 . This is not a get rich scheme . Why work for 
>   somebody else when you can become rich within 92 WEEKS  . Have you
>   ever noticed most everyone has a cellphone  plus nearly every
>   commercial on television has a .com  on in it ! Well, now is your
>   chance to capitalize on  this ! We will help you decrease perceived
>   waiting  time by 120% and process your orders within seconds  . You
>   can begin at absolutely no cost to you . But  don't believe us . Ms
>   Ames of Mississippi tried us  and says "Now I'm rich, Rich, RICH" . We
>   are licensed  to operate in all states . We urge you to contact us 
>   today for your own future financial well-being . Sign  up a friend and
>   your friend will be rich too . God  Bless ! Dear Web surfer ; This
>   letter was specially  selected to be sent to you ! If you are not
>   interested  in our publications and wish to be removed from our 
>   lists, simply do NOT respond and ignore this mail .  This mail is
>   being sent in compliance with Senate bill  1619 ; Title 3 ; Section
>   301 ! THIS IS NOT MULTI-LEVEL  MARKETING . Why work for somebody else
>   when you can  become rich in 41 DAYS ! Have you ever noticed people 
>   love convenience plus most everyone has a cellphone  . Well, now is
>   your chance to capitalize on this !  We will help you deliver goods
>   right to the customer's  doorstep and deliver goods right to the
>   customer's  doorstep . You can begin at absolutely no cost to you  .
>   But don't believe us . Mrs Simpson of Montana tried  us and says "My
>   only problem now is where to park all  my cars" ! This offer is 100%
>   legal ! DO NOT DELAY 
>   - order today . Sign up a friend and you'll get a discount  of 50% ! Warmest regards !

It's rather wordy and not practical for heavy use, but it gives you an idea. In general auto generating believable text is very difficult, hence the use of SPAM as it tends to blend in with other unbelievable text.

Comment: Dunno why this was downvoted - this points to a tool that is aimed at addressing the OP's problem (whether it does so successfully can be argued; that it tries to do so cannot be)